# Create Index not working using MongoDb in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I am creating index for mongodb in my golang application using the below code

```
mod := mongo.IndexModel{
        Keys: bson.D{
            {"key1", 1},
            {"key2", 1},
            {"key3",1},// index in ascending order
        }, Options:  options.Index().SetUnique(true),
    }
    _, err = ds.database.Collection("collectionname").Indexes().CreateOne(context.Background(), mod)
```

After this code executes  when I check the indexes in mongodb via mongoshell I dont see those keys for which I created index .Also the error field is showing me below values.

Err = {error | go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsonrw.TransitionError}
name = {string} "WriteArray"

Comment: Your Go code is OK. The error is likely in your data. Index creation will fail if you already have data that would violate the index (e.g. duplicates when you specify the `unique` option), or the type of the indexed property is not supported (e.g. multiple of them are arrays).

Comment: what version of Mongo are you using?  Background index builds went out around version 4.2

Comment: Have you tried to create the index manually with the same rules?

Comment: @barrypicker I am using 4.0 manually u mean how .I have created in monogoshell and there is works but not through the above code

Comment: just forgot to mention I am using documentDb but I dont think that has to with this